# Why do my secrets cause a KeyError on replit?

Tags: python, replit

When I was on replit.com I created a secret to hide some of my code and it is stopping my code from working. You can see the error at: [Question 1 (From sussy baka mission)](https://replit.com/@MrSquisaac/Question-1-From-sussy-baka-mission?v=1).

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import funcs_one as fun
  File "/home/runner/o4w7JEz5k0X/funcs_one.py", line 3, in <module>
    lol1 = os.environ['lol1']
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'lol1'
```

My `main.py` `import funcs_one as fun` then `fun.run()`
My file `funcs_one.py` has the code:

```
import os

lol1 = os.environ['lol1']
lol2 = os.environ['lol2']
my_secret = os.environ['option1']
my_secret2 = os.environ['option2']
my_secret3 = os.environ['option3']
my_secret4 = os.environ['option4']
my_secret5 = os.environ['option5']
my_secret6 = os.environ['option6']
my_secret7 = os.environ['option7']
my_secret8 = os.environ['option8']

def run():
  var = input("""Fowards, im heavy. Backwards, im not (No caps)
""")
  if var == my_secret2:
    print(lol2)

  elif var == my_secret:
    print(lol1)

  elif var == my_secret3:
    print(lol1)

  elif var == my_secret4:
    print(lol1)

  elif var == my_secret5:
    print(lol1)

  elif var == my_secret6:
    print(lol1)

  elif var == my_secret7:
    print(lol1)

  elif var == my_secret8:
    print(lol1)
  else:
    print("That is not a reasonable answer, please try again")
    run()
```

Comment: I also added `import os` at the start of `funcs_one.py`

Comment: I am not familiar with replit, but from the error message it appears there's no environment variable named `lol1` defined when you run your code — it looks like you can define them though, see [Adding, Viewing and Editing Environment Variables](https://docs.replit.com/programming-ide/storing-sensitive-information-environment-variables#adding-viewing-and-editing-environment-variables).

Comment: Adding onto the above: please edit your post to describe how you're setting up environment variables.

Comment: The error tells you that the key `'lol1'` doesn't exist in the dictionary `os.environ`. Why do you expect this key to exist?

Comment: i used the sidebar and went onto "secrets" and defined it there. It also works for me but when i go into incognito or another account it doesn't